# bootstrap rows overlapping instead of stacking

Tags: html, css, frontend, bootstrap-5

I'm building a page using bootstrap. The idea is to have different sections, each using a bootstrap row inside a container.

The problem is that, when I add new rows, instead of appearing below the previous row, they are appearing behind it.

In my understanding the rows should appear below each other, does anyone have an idea of what is going on?

Issue photo:
[image]

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  const image = new Image();
  image.src = document.getElementById("img-rocket").getAttribute("src");

  const explosion = new Image();
  explosion.src = document.getElementById("img-explosion").getAttribute("src");

  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  const colors = {
    leftMeasures: "#f00",
    borderColor: "#252e39",
    rocketLineColor: "#9c3d92",
    fontColor: "#51596a",
    textColor: "#fff",
    timerColor: "#1b2430",
    stopColor: "#e82b4a",
  };

  const GRAPH_TOP = 50;
  const GRAPH_BOTTOM = 350;
  const GRAPH_LEFT = 75;
  const GRAPH_RIGHT = 650;

  const GRAPH_HEIGHT = 350;
  const GRAPH_WIDTH = 650;

  const initialLines = () => [{
      x1: GRAPH_LEFT,
      y1: 265.5,
      x2: GRAPH_RIGHT,
      y2: 265.5,
      timer: "x1.25",
    },
    {
      x1: GRAPH_LEFT,
      y1: 80,
      x2: GRAPH_RIGHT,
      y2: 80,
      timer: "x1.5",
    },
    {
      x1: GRAPH_LEFT,
      y1: -10,
      x2: GRAPH_RIGHT,
      y2: -10,
      timer: "x1.75",
    },
  ];

  const initialState = {
    status: "running",
    loading: 500,
    speed_minus: 1,
    isStarted: false,
    id: 1,
    lines: [...initialLines()],
    line_curve: -210,
  };

  let game = {
    ...initialState
  };

  let rocket_y = GRAPH_BOTTOM - 10;
  let rocket_x = GRAPH_LEFT + 30;

  const data = [
    2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 40, 50,
    60, 70, 80, 90, 100,
  ];

  let timer = 1;

  function drawLine(time, bottom = 0) {
    game.lines = [
      ...game.lines,
      {
        x1: GRAPH_LEFT,
        y1: GRAPH_TOP + bottom,
        x2: GRAPH_RIGHT,
        y2: GRAPH_TOP + bottom,
        timer: time,
      },
    ];
  }

  function drawLoading(loading) {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
    context.fillStyle = colors.timerColor;
    context.fillRect(
      GRAPH_WIDTH / 10,
      GRAPH_HEIGHT / 2,
      GRAPH_WIDTH / 1.15,
      50
    );

    context.fillStyle = colors.stopColor;

    const loadingPercent = loading / 500;
    const loadingWidth = (loadingPercent * GRAPH_WIDTH) / 1.18;

    context.fillRect(GRAPH_WIDTH / 9, GRAPH_HEIGHT / 1.9, loadingWidth, 30);

    context.fillStyle = "#fff";
    context.font = "500 1rem Segoe UI";
    context.fillText(
      "Começando em " + (loading / 100).toFixed(1).toString() + "s",
      GRAPH_WIDTH / 2.5,
      (GRAPH_HEIGHT + 60) / 2
    );

    window.requestAnimationFrame(drawGraph);
  }

  function drawGraph() {
    console.log(GRAPH_TOP);
    if (game.status === "loading") return handleLoading();
    // else if (game.status === "paused")
    //   return window.requestAnimationFrame(drawGraph);

    context.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);

    context.lineWidth = 2.5;
    context.lineCap = "round";

    context.font = "600 0.8rem Segoe UI";
    context.fillStyle = colors.fontColor;
    context.textAlign = "center";
    context.setLineDash([6, 5]);

    for (let line of game.lines) {
      context.beginPath();
      context.strokeStyle = colors.borderColor;

      context.moveTo(line.x1, line.y1);
      context.lineTo(line.x2, line.y2);

      context.fillText(line.timer, GRAPH_LEFT - 30, line.y1 + 5);
      context.stroke();

      if (game.status === "running") {
        /// Movimento e criação das linhas
        const speed =
          (line.y1 - GRAPH_BOTTOM) / GRAPH_HEIGHT / game.speed_minus;

        line.y1 -= speed;
        line.y2 -= speed;

        if (line.y1 > 120 && line.y1 < 125 && line.timer === "x2") {
          game.speed_minus = 2;

          game.lines = [{
            ...line
          }];
        } else if (line.y1 > 290) game.lines.shift();
      }
    }

    context.setLineDash([0, 0]);

    /// desenha a borda do gráfico
    context.beginPath();
    context.lineWidth = 4;
    context.strokeStyle = colors.borderColor;
    context.moveTo(GRAPH_LEFT - 10, GRAPH_BOTTOM);
    context.lineTo(GRAPH_RIGHT, GRAPH_BOTTOM);
    // context.lineTo(GRAPH_RIGHT + 25, GRAPH_TOP);
    context.fillText("1x", GRAPH_LEFT - 30, GRAPH_BOTTOM + 2);
    context.stroke();

    /// desenha a linha do foguete
    context.beginPath();
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    context.lineJoin = "round";
    context.strokeStyle = colors.rocketLineColor;

    if (game.status === "running") {
      if (rocket_y > GRAPH_TOP) rocket_y -= 0.5 * 1.2;
      if (rocket_x < GRAPH_RIGHT) rocket_x += 1 * 1.2;

      if (rocket_x > GRAPH_RIGHT / 2 && game.line_curve < -50)
        game.line_curve += 1;
    }

    context.moveTo(GRAPH_LEFT, GRAPH_BOTTOM);
    context.bezierCurveTo(
      GRAPH_LEFT,
      GRAPH_BOTTOM,
      GRAPH_BOTTOM + game.line_curve,
      GRAPH_BOTTOM - 30,
      rocket_x,
      rocket_y
    );

    // context.fillText(i + 1, (GRAPH_RIGHT / arrayLen) * i, GRAPH_BOTTOM + 25);

    context.stroke();

    console.log(game.status);
    if (game.status === "running")
      context.drawImage(image, rocket_x - 45, rocket_y - 30, 70, 70);
    else context.drawImage(explosion, rocket_x - 45, rocket_y - 30, 70, 70);

    drawText(
      timer.toFixed(2) + "X",
      game.status === "running" ? colors.timerColor : colors.stopColor,
      colors.textColor
    );

    if (game.status === "running") handleTimer();

    window.requestAnimationFrame(drawGraph);
  }

  // startGame();

  window.requestAnimationFrame(drawGraph);
  const defeatTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20000 - 5000 + 1)) + 5000;
  setTimeout(stopGame, defeatTime);

  function startGame(t) {
    if (game.isStarted) return;
    game = {
      ...initialState,
      lines: [...initialLines()]
    };
    game.status = "running";

    rocket_y = GRAPH_BOTTOM;
    rocket_x = GRAPH_LEFT;

    console.log(game);

    window.requestAnimationFrame(drawGraph);

    const defeatTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20000 - 5000 + 1)) + 5000;
    setTimeout(stopGame, defeatTime);
  }
  // });

  function drawText(text, bgColor, fontColor) {
    context.fillStyle = bgColor;
    context.font = "bolder 1.8rem Segoe UI";
    context.fillRect(
        (GRAPH_WIDTH - 80) / 2.2,
        GRAPH_HEIGHT / 2.5,
        GRAPH_WIDTH / 3.5,
        100
      ),
      (context.fillStyle = fontColor);
    context.fillText(text, (GRAPH_WIDTH + 50) / 2, (GRAPH_HEIGHT + 50) / 2);
  }

  function stopGame() {
    game.status = "paused";

    setTimeout(() => {
      game = {
        ...initialState,
        lines: [...initialLines()],
        status: "loading"
      };
    }, 5000);
  }

  function handleTimer() {
    const formatedTimer = Number(timer.toFixed(2));
    console.log(formatedTimer);
    data.includes(formatedTimer) ? drawLine("x" + formatedTimer) : null;

    timer += 0.0025;
  }

  function handleLoading() {
    game.loading--;
    timer = 1;

    if (game.loading <= 0) startGame(true);
    else drawLoading(game.loading);
  }
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap");
:root {
  --top-header-top-position: 1.5rem;
  --header-height: 3rem;
  --nav-width: 68px;
  --chat-width: 100px;
  --primary-color: var(--bs-primary);
  --secondary-color: var(--bs-secondary);
  --field-gray: var(--bs-field-grey);
  --field-grey-transparency: var(--bs-field-grey-transparency);
  --white-color: var(--bs-white);
  --body-font: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  --normal-font-size: 1rem;
  --z-fixed: 100;
  --z-topbar: 101;
}

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.top-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--top-header-top-position);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  background-color: var(--secondary-color);
  z-index: var(--z-topbar);
  transition: .5s;
  text-align: center !important;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--header-height);
  position: fixed;
  top: var(--top-header-top-position);
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  z-index: var(--z-fixed);
  transition: .5s
}

.main-container-page {
  padding-top: calc(var(--header-height) + var(--top-header-top-position) + 5rem);
  z-index: 5000;
}

.header_toggle {
  color: var(--primary-color);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer
}

.header_img {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden
}

.header_img img {
  width: 40px
}

.l-navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -30%;
  width: var(--nav-width);
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  padding: .5rem 1rem 0 0;
  transition: .5s;
  z-index: var(--z-fixed)
}

.r-navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  padding: 1rem 0 0 1rem;
  transition: .5s;
  z-index: var(--z-fixed);
  padding: 1rem 0 0 1rem;
}

.nav {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

.nav_logo,
.nav_link {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  padding: .5rem 0 .5rem 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav_logo {
  margin-bottom: 2rem
}

.nav_logo-icon {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  color: var(--white-color)
}

.nav_logo-name {
  color: var(--white-color);
  font-weight: 700
}

.nav_link {
  position: relative;
  color: var(--white-color);
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  transition: .3s
}

.nav_link:hover {
  color: var(--white-color)
}

.nav_icon {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.secondary-bs-color {
  color: var(--bs-secondary)
}

.white-bs-color {
  color: var(--white-color)
}

.show-left-nav {
  left: 0;
  width: calc(var(--nav-width) + 156px);
}

.show-right-nav {
  width: 100%;
}

.body-menu-pd {
  padding-left: calc(var(--nav-width) + 188px);
}

.body-chat-pd {
  padding-right: calc(var(--chat-width) + 1rem);
}

.chat-font {
  font-size: small;
}

.time-span-chat {
  font-size: smaller;
  color: var(--white-color);
}

#chatContainer {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  /* for Internet Explorer, Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;
  /* for Firefox */
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#chatContainer::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
  /* for Chrome, Safari, and Opera */
}

.active {
  color: var(--white-color)
}

.active::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: var(--white-color)
}

.height-100 {
  height: 100vh
}

.float-icon-chat {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  background-color: var(--secondary-color);
  color: var(--white-color);
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 100;
}

.coin-dropdown-item {
  color: var(--white-color);
}

.coin-dropdown-item:hover {
  color: var(--secondary-color);
  background-color: var(--field-grey-transparency);
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .header {
    height: calc(var(--header-height) + 1rem);
    padding: 0 2rem 0 calc(var(--nav-width) + 2rem)
  }
  .header_img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px
  }
  .header_img img {
    width: 45px
  }
  .l-navbar {
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem 1rem 0 0
  }
  .r-navbar {
    right: 0;
    padding: 1rem 0 0 1rem;
    width: 0;
  }
  .show-left-nav {
    width: calc(var(--nav-width) + 156px)
  }
  .show-right-nav {
    width: calc(var(--chat-width) + 156px)
  }
  .body-menu-pd {
    padding-left: calc(var(--nav-width) + 188px);
  }
  .body-chat-pd {
    padding-right: calc(var(--chat-width) + 156px)
  }
}


/* Media queries for conditional borders on games */

.game-col {
  border-left: none;
}

.game-block {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.game-top {
  border-top: 1px solid var(--white-color);
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .game-col {
    border-left: 1px solid var(--white-color);
  }
  .game-block {
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--white-color);
  }
  .game-top {
    border-top: none;
  }
}


/* crash game */

.crash-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 750px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: #0f1923;
  margin: 0rem auto 2rem auto;
}


/* betting menu */

.bet-menu-buttons {
  width: 7vh;
  height: 7vh;
}

.bettor-table-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--white-color);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/js/all.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body id="body-pd" style="">

  <!--Container Main start-->
  <img style="display: none;" src="./img/foguete.png" alt="foguete" id="img-rocket" />
  <img style="display: none;" src="./img/explosion.png" alt="explosion" id="img-explosion" />

  <div class="height-100 main-container-page">
    <div class="container h-100">
      <div class="row h-50 gx-0">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-5 order-sm-1 order-2 bg-opacity-white bg-opacity-25 text-center game-top ps-5 pe-5 d-flex flex-column justify-content-evenly">
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <span class="border-0 bg-field-grey text-white fw-bold input-group-text">Amount</span>
            <span class="border-0 bg-field-grey text-white fw-bold input-group-text">TC</span>
            <input type="text" class="border-0 bg-field-grey text-white form-control" placeholder="select value here" aria-label="Dollar amount (with dot and two decimal places)">
          </div>

          <div class="d-flex justify-content-evenly align-items-center">
            <div class="bet-menu-buttons bg-primary text-white fw-bold border border-primary border-4 rounded ms-2 me-2">
              2X
            </div>
            <div class="bet-menu-buttons bg-primary text-white fw-bold border border-primary border-4 rounded ms-2 me-2">
              10X
            </div>
            <div class="bet-menu-buttons bg-primary text-white fw-bold border border-primary border-4 rounded ms-2 me-2">
              1/2
            </div>
            <div class="bet-menu-buttons bg-primary text-white fw-bold border border-primary border-4 rounded ms-2 me-2">
              +5
            </div>
            <div class="bet-menu-buttons bg-primary text-white fw-bold border border-primary border-4 rounded ms-2 me-2">
              +10
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-evenly align-items-center">
            <span class="text-white fw-bold mb-2">
                Auto stop
              </span>
            <input type="text" class="border-0 bg-field-grey text-white form-control border border-field-grey rounded-pill" placeholder="0.00 format" aria-label="auto stop">
          </div>

          <div class="d-flex flex-column mt-5">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary fw-bold border border-secondary rounded-pill">Bet</button>

            <button disabled class="btn btn-secondary fw-bold border border-secondary rounded-pill mt-5">Stop</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-7 order-sm-2 order-1 bg-opacity-white bg-opacity-25 text-center game-col">

          <div class="d-flex h-80 game-block pt-4 ps-4 pe-4">
            <canvas class="crash-canvas" id="canvas" height="400px" width="700px"></canvas>
          </div>

          <div class="d-flex flex-column h-35 game-top ps-3 pt-3 pb-5">
            <div class="d-flex text-white fw-bold ms-1 mb-2">
              Last runs:
            </div>

            <div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
              <span class="badge bg-primary ms-1 me-1">2.37x</span>
              <span class="badge bg-primary ms-1 me-1">2.37x</span>
              <span class="badge bg-primary ms-1 me-1">2.37x</span>
              <span class="badge bg-primary ms-1 me-1">2.37x</span>
              <span class="badge bg-primary ms-1 me-1">2.37x</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row mt-5 gx-0 bg-dark bg-opacity-25">
        <div class="col-12 mt-3 mb-3">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <div class="text-secondary ms-5" style="font-size: large"><span class="fw-bold">0 players</span> made their bets</div>

            <div class="text-white me-5" style="font-size: larger;"><span class="fw-bold">0 TC</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <table class="table-primary table-borderless w-90">
              <thead class="text-white fw-bold bg-field-grey" style="height: 6vh;">
                <th class="w-70">User</th>
                <th class="w-10">Bet</th>
                <th class="w-10">Multiplier</th>
                <th class="w-10">Profit</th>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr class="bettor-table-item text-white fw-bold">
                  <td>
                    Elon musk
                  </td>
                  <td>15 TC</td>
                  <td>4.00x</td>
                  <td>60 TC</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Container Main end-->
</body>
```

Fiddle representing the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/aeo910rb/

The second row (the one appearing behind the first row was set with bg-dark in the fiddle to make it easier to see what is going on)

Comment: Can you post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [Code snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Just editted the post to add a jsfidddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aeo910rb/

Comment: Isn't it the fixed height on your canvas that's going "outside" of the right col and so, overstepping on your row under ?
Your divs are correctly closed from what I checked, and your row is indeed starting after your 2 cols (the left and right) since it's started outside the first row.

Comment: The js defines the canvas, which apparently is relevant to the question as per some of the answers here, therefore I believe we should keep it in the question

Comment: You've set a fixed height on the first row, though that doesn't allow enough space. What are your actual layout requirements?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's your **fixed** `height` of the canvas that is the causing the overstepping on your `row`. It is set to `400px` and if you go responsive, it does overstep on your `row`.

You should use **relative** `height`, so the canvas is set to follow its parent size and not overstep.

For example, you could put your canvas in `height: 100%` and set a fixed size to the parent of the canvas. That way, your canvas will not overstep its parent, and so...not overstep on the row underneath.

---

You also have a slight issue on **responsive**, some elements are out of a `div`. There is too much `padding` on both **left** and **right** side, causing the div to be too small to "digest" your elements. Maybe you could also modify the `flex` div that has the **blue bets buttons** so it's a `row` (or has a `flex-wrap: wrap`) for the elements not to be forced as a row.

Here's a link on the `flex-wrap` documentation : [flex-wrap-MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap)

As shown under :
[image: example]

Comment: It works, but the page is still stacking on sm viewport

Comment: Could you take a screen shot of what i does, because for me, the canvas looks fine on my tests. 
You do have some other elements getting out of their parent's div (as shown in updated answer), but that's basically all I see right now